# Узнать длину строки по заданному шрифту

Tags: javascript, canvas, шрифты

Можно с помощью JS через canvas или другим способом узнать длину строки по заданному шрифту и его величине в миллиметрах? Через метод measureText() можно получить длину в пикселях.

Comment: Миллиметров не существует. Что требуется получить в итоге?

Comment: переменная `devicePixelRatio` может быть полезной

Comment: Понятие миллиметры в мониторе не существует, размер пикселя всегда разный.

Answer (score 1):

Через метод measureText() получаете значение длины в пикселях, а дальше умножаете на 0.2645833333333, таков стандартный размер пикселя в миллиметрах. В случае ретина дисплеев делите на 2. Какова задача таково и решение. Нафига вам миллиметры не понятно. Может вы мониторы производите - откуда я знаю то.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Text(phrase, fontsize)
{
   let ml = 0.2645833333333;
   return phrase.split('').length*fontsize*ml;
};
```

В функцию передаем саму фразу и размер шрифта. Получаем количество букв с помощью `phrase.split('').length`, умножаем на `fontsize` и получаем количество пикселей, занимаемое фразой. Умножаем на 0.2645833333333 (размер 1 пкс в мм)

Answer (score 1):

Как-то сталкивался с подобной задачей. Подсчет количества букв - сразу не подошел. Например i и w имеют разную ширину. Отличный вариант - пихать текст в инлайновый элемент и смотреть на его ширину в пикселях, а потом можно умноджить на размер пиксля:

```js
var _result = document.getElementById('result');
var _test = document.getElementById('test');

function count(){
    var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
    _test.innerHTML = text;
    _result.innerHTML = _test.offsetWidth;
}
```

```css
#test{
  display: inline;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<input id="input" type="text" oninput="count()">
<div>
Длина фразы: <span id="result"></span> пикселей
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Стандартного размера пикселя" не существует! Все зависит от разрешающих возможностей устройства вывода. Загляните в вики, прочтите про [DPI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch). Далее формула пересчета станет очевидной:

- знаем DPI (сколько пикселей устройство вывода укладывает в дюйм)
- знаем сколько пикселей приходится на строку
- осталось перевести дюймы в миллиметры